# how to iterate the list and build tree

Tags: flutter, dart

i have two cards in in row and each time row creates with two card i have data in my list and when list iterates it creates same name of card

i have an array of subcatextra and SubCategory class that have data i want to show first object name sub.name on first card and on second card name should be the next object of subcatextra list , i don't know how to achieve this please ** help me ***
here is my code

```
ListView(
    children:     subcatextra.map<Widget>((SubCategory sub)
{
  return Row(

    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        width: (MediaQuery
            .of(context)
            .size
            .width / 2) - 20,
        height: 90,
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: (){},
          child: Card(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
            ),
            elevation: 1,
            child: Container(
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                      height: 70,
                      width: 80,
                      child: Image.network(
                          "https://smartbasket.pk/image/cache/data/Bazaarapna/dairy%20product/Haleeb%20Milk%20%E2%80%93%2001%20Litre%20(Pack%20of%2012)-500x500.jpg",
                          fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                  Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
                      child: Text(sub.name, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),))
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Spacer(),
      Container(
        width: (MediaQuery
            .of(context)
            .size
            .width / 2) - 20,
        height: 90,
        child: Card(
          elevation: 1,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
          ),

          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                  height: 70,
                  width: 80,
                  child: Image.network(
                      "https://smartbasket.pk/image/cache/data/Bazaarapna/dairy%20product/Haleeb%20Milk%20%E2%80%93%2001%20Litre%20(Pack%20of%2012)-500x500.jpg",
                      fit: BoxFit.cover)),
              Text(sub.name, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),)
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
    ],
  );
}).toList()
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a ListView.builder, create two variables for each object and assign them according the index being even or odd. Bellow follows a complete example that you cant test at [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: CardListView()));
}

class CardListView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CardListViewState createState() => _CardListViewState();
}

class _CardListViewState extends State<CardListView> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  List<String> list = [
    'name1',
    'name2',
    'name3',
    'name4',
    'name5',
    'name6',
    'name7',
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Title")),
      body: new ListView.builder(
        itemCount: list.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
          String firstCellContent = '';
          String secondCellContent = '';

          if (index % 2 == 0) {
            firstCellContent = list[index];
            if (index + 1 < list.length - 1) {
              secondCellContent = list[index + 1];
            } else {
              secondCellContent = '';
            }
          }
          return Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                child: new Text(
                  firstCellContent,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                child: new Text(
                  secondCellContent,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```